# Organize JSON data in HTML table with unique header rows for each data group

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, fetch-api

I have a JSON object that includes a key:value pair called **callRoot**. Example values for this key:value pair include **@S**, **@C**, and **@W**. There are multiple objects that have the same value and I hoping to set a HTML table head row at the start of each grouping and repeat it for each group of data.

**Update**

Fetch API function for accessing remote API data:

```
const fetchData = function() {
  const apiKey = "";
  const request = `https://apiurl.com`;

  fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => foo(data))
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
fetchData();
```

**Update Two**

```
for (let i of filtered[property]) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tblBody.appendChild(tr);
  data.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
  });
```

Sample JSON data:

```
const data = [
  {
    "symbol": {
      "description": "SOYBEANS January 2022"
    },
    "actualSymbol": "@SF22",
    "high": {
      "number": 1396
    },
    "low": {
      "number": 1374.75
    },
    "close": null,
    "settlePrice": {
      "number": 1401.5
    },
    "last": {
      "number": 1378
    },
    "change": {
      "number": -23.5
    },
    "month": "Jan 22",
    "callRoot": "@S",
    "userDescription": "SOYBEANS",
  },
  {
    "symbol": {
      "description": "SOYBEANS March 2022"
    },
    "actualSymbol": "@SH22",
    "high": {
      "number": 1409.75
    },
    "low": {
      "number": 1379
    },
    "close": null,
    "settlePrice": {
      "number": 1410.25
    },
    "last": {
      "number": 1383.25
    },
    "change": {
      "number": -27
    },
    "month": "Mar 22",
    "callRoot": "@S",
    "userDescription": "SOYBEANS",
  },
  {
  "symbol": {
    "description": "SOYBEANS May 2022",
   },
  "actualSymbol": "@SK22",
  "high": {
    "number": 1418
  },
  "low": {
    "number": 1387.5
  },
  "close": null,
  "settlePrice": {
    "number": 1418.75
  },
  "last": {
    "number": 1391.25
  },
  "change": {
    "number": -27.5
  },
  "month": "May 22",
  "callRoot": "@S",
  "userDescription": "SOYBEANS",
},
{
  "symbol": {
    "description": "CORN March 2022",
  },
  "actualSymbol": "@CH22",
  "high": {
    "number": 608
  },
  "low": {
    "number": 596.75
  },
  "close": null,
  "settlePrice": {
    "number": 606.75
  },
  "last": {
    "number": 599.25
  },
  "change": {
    "number": -7.5
  },
  "month": "Mar 22",
  "callRoot": "@C",
  "userDescription": "CORN",
},
{
  "symbol": {
    "description": "CORN May 2022",
  },
  "actualSymbol": "@CK22",
  "high": {
    "number": 608.5
  },
  "low": {
    "number": 598.25
  },
  "close": null,
  "settlePrice": {
    "number": 607.75
  },
  "last": {
    "number": 600.75
  },
  "change": {
    "number": -7
  },
  "month": "May 22",
  "callRoot": "@C",
  "userDescription": "CORN",
},
{
  "symbol": {
    "description": "CORN July 2022",
  },
  "actualSymbol": "@CN22",
  "high": {
    "number": 605.25
  },
  "low": {
    "number": 595.5
  },
  "close": null,
  "settlePrice": {
    "number": 604.5
  },
  "last": {
    "number": 598
  },
  "change": {
    "number": -6.5
  },
  "month": "Jul 22",
  "callRoot": "@C",
  "userDescription": "CORN",
},
{
  "symbol": {
    "description": "WHEAT March 2022",
  },
  "actualSymbol": "@WH22",
  "high": {
    "number": 767.5
  },
  "low": {
    "number": 748
  },
  "close": null,
  "settlePrice": {
    "number": 758.5
  },
  "last": {
    "number": 763.75
  },
  "change": {
    "number": 5.25
  },
  "month": "Mar 22",
  "callRoot": "@W",
  "userDescription": "WHEAT",
},
{
  "symbol": {
    "description": "WHEAT May 2022",
  },
  "actualSymbol": "@WK22",
  "high": {
    "number": 768.5
  },
  "low": {
    "number": 750
  },
  "close": null,
  "settlePrice": {
    "number": 760.5
  },
  "last": {
    "number": 765.5
  },
  "change": {
    "number": 5
  },
  "month": "May 22",
  "callRoot": "@W",
  "userDescription": "WHEAT",
},
{
  "symbol": {
    "description": "WHEAT July 2022",
  },
  "actualSymbol": "@WN22",
  "high": {
    "number": 763.25
  },
  "low": {
    "number": 747.25
  },
  "close": null,
  "settlePrice": {
    "number": 757
  },
  "last": {
    "number": 760.5
  },
  "change": {
    "number": 3.5
  },
  "month": "Jul 22",
  "callRoot": "@W",
  "userDescription": "WHEAT",
}
```

];

Here is some of the code I have been playing with, though I could be way off on achieving my set requirements. A switch statement may be better suited than the `if/else if statement`

```
// Create empty arrays for each callRoot grouping
const soybeans = [];
const corn = [];
const wheat = [];

for(let commodity of commodities) {
  let callRoot = commodity.callRoot;
  if(callRoot.includes("@S")) {

  } else if(callRoot.includes("@C")) {

  } else if(callRoot.includes("@W")) {
  
  }
}

const soyHeader = soybean[0];
if(soyHeader) {
  // Render table header row HTML
}
// Render table row HTML

const cornHeader = corn[0];
if(cornHeader) {
  // Render table header row HTML
}
// Render table row HTML

const wheatHeader = wheat[0];
if(wheatHeader) {
  // Render table header row HTML
}
// Render table row HTML
```

Example HTML table structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">SOYBEANS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Last</td>
      <td>Change</td>
      <td>High</td>
      <td>Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August 2022</td>
      <td>1265'2</td>
      <td>-2'4</td>
      <td>1275'2</td>
      <td>1261'4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August 2022</td>
      <td>1265'2</td>
      <td>-2'4</td>
      <td>1275'2</td>
      <td>1261'4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">CORN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Last</td>
      <td>Change</td>
      <td>High</td>
      <td>Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August 2022</td>
      <td>1265'2</td>
      <td>-2'4</td>
      <td>1275'2</td>
      <td>1261'4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August 2022</td>
      <td>1265'2</td>
      <td>-2'4</td>
      <td>1275'2</td>
      <td>1261'4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">WHEAT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Last</td>
      <td>Change</td>
      <td>High</td>
      <td>Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August 2022</td>
      <td>1265'2</td>
      <td>-2'4</td>
      <td>1275'2</td>
      <td>1261'4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August 2022</td>
      <td>1265'2</td>
      <td>-2'4</td>
      <td>1275'2</td>
      <td>1261'4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Rendered HTML table example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a function which creates exactly the table from your example

Here my script/function:

**OLD Function with the wrong Data but right ouput .-.**

```js
const filterData = function (data) {
    const filtered = {};
    data.forEach(element => { // going through all the elements
        if (filtered[element.callRoot]) filtered[element.callRoot].push(element); // if callRoot already exists in filtered object
        else filtered[element.callRoot] = [element]; // else create property with callRoot as name -> here we push all the objects with the same callRoot name
    })
    return filtered;
};

const foo = function (data, element) {
    const filtered = filterData(data);

    // starting to create Table

    // creating static table element, here becomes the element argument useful
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    element.appendChild(table);

    // now we start creating the tbodies, trs and tds with the filtered data

    // so we go through our filtered object by looping through an array of the keys ('@S','@C','@W')
    Object.keys(filtered).forEach(property => {

        // for each property we will create the tbody and tr + th and append them
        const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        const th = document.createElement('th');
        th.setAttribute('colspan', 9); // adding colspan attribute
        th.textContent = filtered[property][0].userDescription; // taking the description as th text
        tr.appendChild(th);

        // now we create the rest of the tbody

        // since i dont know where the data for the table comes from i will use the defined data from your example html output

        // creating tr for our header tds
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        const definedDataArrayHeaders = ['Month', 'Last', 'Change', 'High', 'Low']; // headers from your example
        definedDataArrayHeaders.forEach(element => { // going through the headers
            const td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = element; // writing the header inside the td
            tr.appendChild(td);
        });

        const definedDataArrayTds = ['August 2022', "1265'2", "-2'4", "1275'2", "1261'4"]; // tds from your example
        for (let i of filtered[property]) { // will loop through each object inside our filtered array -> each tr in our future table
            const tr = document.createElement('tr'); // creating tr for each data
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            definedDataArrayTds.forEach(element => { // looping through the td data
                const td = document.createElement('td');
                td.textContent = element; // writing the data inside the td
                tr.appendChild(td);
            })
        }
    })


}

foo(commodities, document.querySelector('div')); // calling the function with data and Element where the table should be appended to
```

**FALSE OLD used data:**

```js
const commodities = [
    {
        actualSymbol: "@SF22",
        callRoot: "@S",
        open: 1.00,
        close: 2.00,
        userDescription: "SOYBEANS",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@SH22",
        callRoot: "@S",
        open: 4.00,
        close: 6.00,
        userDescription: "SOYBEANS",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@SK22",
        callRoot: "@S",
        open: 0.50,
        close: 2.30,
        userDescription: "SOYBEANS",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@CH22",
        callRoot: "@C",
        open: 0.25,
        close: 0.75,
        userDescription: "CORN",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@CK22",
        callRoot: "@C",
        open: 5.00,
        close: 6.75,
        userDescription: "CORN",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@CN22",
        callRoot: "@C",
        open: 1.00,
        close: 2.00,
        userDescription: "CORN",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@WH22",
        callRoot: "@W",
        open: 3.25,
        close: 2.00,
        userDescription: "WHEAT",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@WK22",
        callRoot: "@W",
        open: 1.00,
        close: 2.00,
        userDescription: "WHEAT",
        // Other data
    },
    {
        actualSymbol: "@WN22",
        callRoot: "@W",
        open: 0.10,
        close: 0.20,
        userDescription: "WHEAT",
        // Other data
    }
];
```

**But with the RIGHT example output this is the html output:**

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9">SOYBEANS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Month</td>
                <td>Last</td>
                <td>Change</td>
                <td>High</td>
                <td>Low</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9">CORN</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Month</td>
                <td>Last</td>
                <td>Change</td>
                <td>High</td>
                <td>Low</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9">WHEAT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Month</td>
                <td>Last</td>
                <td>Change</td>
                <td>High</td>
                <td>Low</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>August 2022</td>
                <td>1265'2</td>
                <td>-2'4</td>
                <td>1275'2</td>
                <td>1261'4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**New Solution, hope this one is working right haha**

**Here the new version of the script, its definitely not good so just take it as a guideline to come up with your own solution**

```
const filterData2 = function (data) {
    const filtered = {};
    const wantedData = ['month', 'change', 'last', 'high', 'low', 'settlePrice'];
    data.forEach(element => { // going through all the elements
        // now using userDescript as key since its a bit more precise
        if (filtered[element.userDescription]) { // if userDescription already exists in filtered object
            const piece = [];
            // now we extract only the data we need for our html table:
            Object.entries(element).forEach(array => {
                if (wantedData.includes(array[0])) array[1]?.number ? piece.push([array[0], array[1].number]) : piece.push([array[0], array[1]]);
            });
            filtered[element.userDescription].push(piece);
        }
        else {// else create property with userDescription as name -> here we push all the objects with the same callRoot name
            const piece = [];
            filtered[element.userDescription] = [];
            Object.entries(element).forEach(array => {
                if (wantedData.includes(array[0])) array[1]?.number ? piece.push([array[0], array[1].number]) : piece.push([array[0], array[1]]);
            });
            filtered[element.userDescription].push(piece);
        }
    })
    return filtered;
};


// needed since i structured my filtered data different
const getValue = (arr, string) => arr.find(pair => pair[0] === string);

const foo2 = function (data, element) {
    const filtered = filterData2(data);

    // starting to create Table

    // creating static table element, here becomes the element argument useful
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    element.appendChild(table);

    // now we start creating the tbodies, trs and tds with the filtered data

    // so we go through our filtered object by looping through an array of the keys in example:('SOYBEANS','CORN','WHEAT')
    Object.keys(filtered).forEach(key => {

        // key will be either 'SOYBEANS', 'CORN', 'WHEAT' - in this example in exactly this order

        // for each key we will create the tbody and tr + th and append them
        const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        let tr = document.createElement('tr'); // using let here since we are going to overwrite this variable later so we dont have to create a new one
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        const th = document.createElement('th');
        th.setAttribute('colspan', 9); // adding colspan attribute
        th.textContent = key; // taking the key as a header
        tr.appendChild(th);

        // now we create the rest of the tbody

        // now since we filtered the data so in our filtered variable are only the necessary values for our table except the Settle Date

        // creating tr for our header tds
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        const definedDataArrayHeaders = ['MONTH', 'LAST', 'CHANGE', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'SETTLE DATE', 'SETTLE PRICE', 'MORE']; // Headers for the Table, can be anything - keep in Mind the date must be coming from somewhere for these headers, just some are covered by the filtered Array
        definedDataArrayHeaders.forEach(header => { // going through the headers
            const td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = header; // writing the header inside the td
            tr.appendChild(td); // tr we created outside, so they all come into the same row
        });

        const definedDataArrayTds = ['month', "last", "change", "high", "low", "missing", "settlePrice", "missing"]; // this array must contain the names of the values inside the filtered array and must be in the same order as "definedDataArrayHeaders" so the data is in the right column

        // since the Settle date and more value arent in the data/filtered array i will take placeholders so the table still renders right

        // this part is needed to be changed a lot, since the data is now structured completely different

        for (let i of filtered[key]) { // will loop through each object inside our filtered array -> each tr in our future table
            const tr = document.createElement('tr'); // creating tr for each data
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            definedDataArrayTds.forEach(element => { // looping through the td data
                const td = document.createElement('td');
                td.textContent = getValue(i, element)?.[1] || 'PLACEHOLDER'; // writing the data inside the td
                tr.appendChild(td);
            })
        }
    })
}

foo2(data, document.querySelector('div'));
```

**data used in this new example:**

```js
const data = [
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "SOYBEANS January 2022"
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@SF22",
        "high": {
            "number": 1396
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 1374.75
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 1401.5
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 1378
        },
        "change": {
            "number": -23.5
        },
        "month": "Jan 22",
        "callRoot": "@S",
        "userDescription": "SOYBEANS",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "SOYBEANS March 2022"
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@SH22",
        "high": {
            "number": 1409.75
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 1379
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 1410.25
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 1383.25
        },
        "change": {
            "number": -27
        },
        "month": "Mar 22",
        "callRoot": "@S",
        "userDescription": "SOYBEANS",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "SOYBEANS May 2022",
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@SK22",
        "high": {
            "number": 1418
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 1387.5
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 1418.75
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 1391.25
        },
        "change": {
            "number": -27.5
        },
        "month": "May 22",
        "callRoot": "@S",
        "userDescription": "SOYBEANS",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "CORN March 2022",
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@CH22",
        "high": {
            "number": 608
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 596.75
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 606.75
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 599.25
        },
        "change": {
            "number": -7.5
        },
        "month": "Mar 22",
        "callRoot": "@C",
        "userDescription": "CORN",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "CORN May 2022",
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@CK22",
        "high": {
            "number": 608.5
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 598.25
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 607.75
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 600.75
        },
        "change": {
            "number": -7
        },
        "month": "May 22",
        "callRoot": "@C",
        "userDescription": "CORN",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "CORN July 2022",
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@CN22",
        "high": {
            "number": 605.25
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 595.5
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 604.5
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 598
        },
        "change": {
            "number": -6.5
        },
        "month": "Jul 22",
        "callRoot": "@C",
        "userDescription": "CORN",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "WHEAT March 2022",
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@WH22",
        "high": {
            "number": 767.5
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 748
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 758.5
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 763.75
        },
        "change": {
            "number": 5.25
        },
        "month": "Mar 22",
        "callRoot": "@W",
        "userDescription": "WHEAT",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "WHEAT May 2022",
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@WK22",
        "high": {
            "number": 768.5
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 750
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 760.5
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 765.5
        },
        "change": {
            "number": 5
        },
        "month": "May 22",
        "callRoot": "@W",
        "userDescription": "WHEAT",
    },
    {
        "symbol": {
            "description": "WHEAT July 2022",
        },
        "actualSymbol": "@WN22",
        "high": {
            "number": 763.25
        },
        "low": {
            "number": 747.25
        },
        "close": null,
        "settlePrice": {
            "number": 757
        },
        "last": {
            "number": 760.5
        },
        "change": {
            "number": 3.5
        },
        "month": "Jul 22",
        "callRoot": "@W",
        "userDescription": "WHEAT",
    }
];
```

**Output with the above data example**

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9">SOYBEANS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MONTH</td>
                <td>LAST</td>
                <td>CHANGE</td>
                <td>HIGH</td>
                <td>LOW</td>
                <td>SETTLE DATE</td>
                <td>SETTLE PRICE</td>
                <td>MORE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jan 22</td>
                <td>1378</td>
                <td>-23.5</td>
                <td>1396</td>
                <td>1374.75</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>1401.5</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mar 22</td>
                <td>1383.25</td>
                <td>-27</td>
                <td>1409.75</td>
                <td>1379</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>1410.25</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>May 22</td>
                <td>1391.25</td>
                <td>-27.5</td>
                <td>1418</td>
                <td>1387.5</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>1418.75</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9">CORN</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MONTH</td>
                <td>LAST</td>
                <td>CHANGE</td>
                <td>HIGH</td>
                <td>LOW</td>
                <td>SETTLE DATE</td>
                <td>SETTLE PRICE</td>
                <td>MORE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mar 22</td>
                <td>599.25</td>
                <td>-7.5</td>
                <td>608</td>
                <td>596.75</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>606.75</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>May 22</td>
                <td>600.75</td>
                <td>-7</td>
                <td>608.5</td>
                <td>598.25</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>607.75</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jul 22</td>
                <td>598</td>
                <td>-6.5</td>
                <td>605.25</td>
                <td>595.5</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>604.5</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9">WHEAT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MONTH</td>
                <td>LAST</td>
                <td>CHANGE</td>
                <td>HIGH</td>
                <td>LOW</td>
                <td>SETTLE DATE</td>
                <td>SETTLE PRICE</td>
                <td>MORE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mar 22</td>
                <td>763.75</td>
                <td>5.25</td>
                <td>767.5</td>
                <td>748</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>758.5</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>May 22</td>
                <td>765.5</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>768.5</td>
                <td>750</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>760.5</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jul 22</td>
                <td>760.5</td>
                <td>3.5</td>
                <td>763.25</td>
                <td>747.25</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
                <td>757</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Thanks for your code. It has helped me forward. The data/commodities is coming from an API. I have updated my question with the Fetch API code for reference.

Comment: Could you clarify if *data* should be used in all areas or should it be a mix of *data* and *commodities*? I ask this because I am getting this type error: TypeError: element is undefined in the `foo(data, document.querySelector("[data-futures]"));` code. My parent div has the data-futures attribute.

Comment: @MikeHermary so the data i used for the foo function to render the html was the commodities array and only that is passed to the function since it was the only source of data you provided. You can just remove the second argument in the function call and just use a fixed output element, just added it so it is a bit more flexible-> 7th line in the foo function `code element.appendChild(table)`. Have you tried logging if document.querySelector('[data-futures]') is returning the right HTML Element?

Comment: @MikeHermary In your fetch you arent calling the foo function with the element where it should be appended to thats why you getting the error. You can either call the function with data + the element where it should be appended to, or you can remove the second argument in the function declaration and edit line 7 in the function and replace element (just here) with the desired element

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have figured out the foo function issue, but am having issues controlling the length of output of the JSON data. When I console log the data result, each object is repeating multiple times. I have updated my code and attached the log output for reference.

Comment: @MikeHermary is it possible for you to provide a real data example? so what you passing in the foo function? Could be a problem with my function since i coded it according to the simple json example you provided?

Comment: I have updated my original question with the real world JSON data that I have been using for testing. I have limited to API results to three symbols. Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like the data is looping through nine times according to `console.log(data.length)`. I am not sure what is triggering this output.

Comment: @MikeHermary i will try to fix my function -> since the real world data is structured differently than what you had before, my function doesnt work. I hope i can fix that

Comment: @MikeHermary alright, so i looked at the data and it shouldnt be difficult to change the script, just one question, is the "Settle Date" in the data provided? Since i cant find it, i will just use a fixed value for it

Comment: @MikeHermary just updated my answer, if anything is not clear, just ask

Comment: Thanks. I will be testing the code today and will let you know if I have any issues. Thanks again.

Comment: I have tested your code and it looks to have moved me forward with this project. Thanks for your assistance.